# Saying wrong details but I'm typing it correctly - PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to make login system by a tutorial. I'm making everything like in tutorial but it says my details are incorrect and it wont log me in but everything is correct. I can't find is there anywhere mistake in code or something. Any help is welcome!

Index.php code:

```
    <?php #admin/index.php 
           #####[make sure you put this code before any html output]#####

//connect to server
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','pw') or 
           die('could not connect: '. mysqli_connect_error());

//select db
mysqli_select_db($dbc, 'dbname') or die('no db connection');

//check if the login form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['go'])){
    #####form submitted, check data...#####

        //step 1a: sanitise and store data into vars (storing encrypted password)
    $usr = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, htmlentities($_POST['u_name']));
    $psw = SHA1($_POST['u_pass']) ; //using SHA1() to encrypt passwords  

        //step2: create query to check if username and password match
    $q = "SELECT * FROM kasutaja WHERE name='$usr' AND pass='$psw'  ";

    //step3: run the query and store result
    $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    //make sure we have a positive result
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1){
        #########  LOGGING IN  ##########
        //starting a session  
                session_start();

                //creating a log SESSION VARIABLE that will persist through pages   
        $_SESSION['log'] = 'in';

        //redirecting to restricted page
        header('location:restricted.php');
    } else {
                //create an error message   
        $error = 'Wrong details. Please try again'; 
    }
}//end isset go
?> 
<!-- HTML FORM GOES HERE -->

<!-- LOGIN FORM in: admin/index.php -->
<form method="post" action="#">
    <p><label for="u_name">username:</label></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="u_name" value=""></p>

    <p><label for="u_pass">password:</label></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="u_pass" value=""></p>

    <p><button type="submit" name="go">log me in</button></p>
</form>
<!-- A paragraph to display eventual errors -->
<p><strong><?php if(isset($error)){echo $error;}  ?></strong></p>
```

Restricted page code:

```
    <?php #admin/restricted.php 
           #####[make sure you put this code before any html output]#####

//starting the session
session_start();

//checking if a log SESSION VARIABLE has been set
if( !isset($_SESSION['log']) || ($_SESSION['log'] != 'in') ){
        //if the user is not allowed, display a message and a link to go back to login page
    echo "You are not allowed. <a href="index.php">back to login page</a>";

        //then abort the script
    exit();
}

/**
*      ####  CODE FOR LOG OUT #### click here to see the logout tutorial 
*/

?> 
<!-- RESTRICTED PAGE HTML GOES HERE -->
<h1> TEST </h1>
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This is a fix for http://www.cramerz.com/php/php_login_system which contains errors that the OP downloaded from the Web. *No wonder the OP had a hard time.*

It queries the wrong columns for one thing and inserts into the wrong table.

Another error with their code is this line:

```
echo "You are not allowed. <a href="index.php">back to login page</a>";
```

which would throw an error and should read as, and escaping the quotes for `index.php`

```
echo "You are not allowed. <a href=\"index.php\">back to login page</a>";
```

---

**Rewrite**

Most of the Websites have a sort of private section where normal users are not allowed. You can think about an ADMIN section where the webmaster finds his CMS, a private area with sensitive personal information or even just the email manager you use to handle your emails.

All of these cases have something in common: they restrict access to allowed users only, with a login system.

To create an authentication system you will need:

- A database, a table called users with at least three columns: id, username, password
- A HTML form where users fill in their usernames and passwords
- A PHP script that will check if usernames and passwords provided actually exist
- A private area users can access only if successfully logged in

**STEP 1.** create a table called users:

a) Use PhpMyAdmin or any other GUI to quickly create a table

```
CREATE  TABLE  `users` (
`id` INT( 5 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`username` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`password` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL
)
```

b) Insert a couple of users:

```
INSERT  INTO  `users` 
( `id` , `username` , `password` )

VALUES ( NULL , 'john', SHA1('johnPsw' ) ),
       ( NULL ,  'james', SHA1('jamesPsw') ),
( NULL , 'jim', SHA1('jimPsw' ) );
```

PLEASE NOTE: we are using the `SHA1()` function to encrypt passwords.

**STEP 2.** login form:

```
<!-- LOGIN FORM in: admin/index.php -->
<form method="post" action="">
    <p><label for="u_name">username:</label></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="u_name" value=""></p>

    <p><label for="u_pass">password:</label></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="u_pass" value=""></p>

    <p><button type="submit" name="go">log me in</button></p>
</form>
<!-- A paragraph to display eventual errors -->
<p><strong><?php if(isset($error)){echo $error;}  ?></strong></p>
```

**STEP 3.** php script:

```
<?php #admin/index.php 
           #####[make sure you put this code before any html output]#####

//connect to server
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or 
           die('could not connect: '. mysqli_connect_error());

//select db
mysqli_select_db($dbc, 'examples') or die('no db connection');

//check if the login form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['go'])){
    #####form submitted, check data...#####

        //step 1a: sanitise and store data into vars (storing encrypted password)
    $usr = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, htmlentities($_POST['u_name']));
    $psw = SHA1($_POST['u_pass']) ; //using SHA1() to encrypt passwords  

        //step2: create query to check if username and password match
    $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$usr' AND password='$psw'  ";

    //step3: run the query and store result
    $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    //make sure we have a positive result
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1){
        #########  LOGGING IN  ##########
        //starting a session  
                session_start();

                //creating a log SESSION VARIABLE that will persist through pages   
        $_SESSION['log'] = 'in';

        //redirecting to restricted page
        header('location:restricted.php');
    } else {
                //create an error message   
        $error = 'Wrong details. Please try again'; 
    }
}//end isset go
?> 
<!-- HTML FORM GOES HERE -->
```

**STEP 4.** restricted page:

```
<?php #admin/restricted.php 
           #####[make sure you put this code before any html output]#####

//starting the session
session_start();

//checking if a log SESSION VARIABLE has been set
if( !isset($_SESSION['log']) || ($_SESSION['log'] != 'in') ){
        //if the user is not allowed, display a message and a link to go back to login page
    echo "You are not allowed. <a href=\"index.php\">back to login page</a>";

        //then abort the script
    exit();
}


else{

echo "Success!";

}

/**
*      ####  CODE FOR LOG OUT #### click here to see the logout tutorial 
*/

?> 
<!-- RESTRICTED PAGE HTML GOES HERE -->
```

Comment: Hmm now it's loggin ing but it show's that I'm not allowed.

Comment: @Divisor That's some form of success. What I posted works, so whatever you're doing afterwards is beyond my control.